# What does the 'p' mean in enumerator each_slice?

Tags: ruby

Just out of curiosity, what does the **'p**' stand for in **enumerable.each_slice** in Ruby?

For example:

```
(1..3).each_slice(2) {|n| p n}
```

prints:

```
[1, 2]
[3]
```

and

```
(1..3).each_slice(2) {|n| print n}
```

prints:

```
123
```

while:

```
(1..3).each_slice(2) {|n| puts n}
```

prints:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no magic or strange behaviour, **p** refers actually to **Kernel.p**

*each_slice* is iterating for an slice of 2 elements. So:

iteration 1 -> n = [1, 2]
iteration 2 -> n = [3]

*Kernel#p* is writing n.inspect in each iteration, so it writes the strings **[1, 2]** and then **[3]**, each one followed by a new line.

*Kernel#print* writes n followed by the value of **$,** (the field separator, which is **nil** by default), so it writes **[1, 2]** and immediately it writes **[3]**

And finally *Kernel#puts* writes recursively each array followed by a new line. More information about it here: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/227540

Comment: I recommend you to follow that link, there are more interesting things in it.

Comment: Interesting read. The commenter's last point in that email could be simplified to `a.flatten.join("")`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a call to the method [`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p).

> [it] directly writes `obj.inspect` followed by the current output record separator to the program’s standard output.